# How can I integrate the following function?

Tags: calculus

Problem:

How can I calculate $\int_0^2 x\sqrt{x^3+1}dx$?

I have tried integration by parts but it just gets real messy. I tried making $u = x^3+1$ and $dv=x$.

Can you also please suggest numerical methods to approximate the function? Thank you.

Moreover if I was to use the Taylor series as an approximation method, why should I prefer x=1, rather than x=0 or x=2?

Comment: Is this a problem from a textbook? I am not so sure that it can be done

Comment: I am a first year university student, and I've been given this question, could you please explain, in detail why it can not be done? Moreover, can you pleas provide a method to approximate the solution?

Comment: I suspect the real question entails $x^2$ instead of $x$.  Did you copy the question correctly?

Comment: Yes I did, I just checked again.

Comment: If it was just x^2, I would only require to use integration by u substitution.

Comment: If you look at Wolfram alpha, the answer is out of your reach: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*sqrt(x%5E3+%2B1)+from+0+to+2 .  Maybe some printing error there....

Comment: But why is that the answer and why can't it be done my normal integration methods and what is the method used in the link you provided?

Comment: look at the light grey remarks underneath the answers; just too difficult at your level

Comment: But shouldn't there be an approximation method?

Comment: Numerical methods exist to approximate the area under the curve, but that is not what is suggested in the post.

Comment: I edited the post, I would like to know a method of approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is no typo in the integrand, we already know (because od the $\sqrt{x^3+1}$ term) that the antiderivative will contain elliptic integrals of the first and second kind (with nasty arguments).

Concerning the definite integral $$\int_0^2 x\sqrt{x^3+1}\,dx=2 \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};-8\right)\approx 3.91613$$

To get a reasonable approximation, you could develop the integrand as a Taylor series around $x=1$ and integrate termwise.
$$x\sqrt{x^3+1}=\sqrt{2}+\frac{7 (x-1)}{2 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{39 (x-1)^2}{16 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{47
   (x-1)^3}{64 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{277 (x-1)^4}{1024 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{321 (x-1)^5}{4096
   \sqrt{2}}+\frac{1891 (x-1)^6}{32768 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{12737 (x-1)^7}{131072
   \sqrt{2}}+\frac{220851 (x-1)^8}{4194304 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{263341 (x-1)^9}{16777216
   \sqrt{2}}-\frac{6669319 (x-1)^{10}}{134217728 \sqrt{2}}+O\left((x-1)^{11}\right)$$ leading to a value $\frac{143031897707}{25836912640 \sqrt{2}}\approx 3.91451$ which is not too bad.

**Edit**

Just to answer a question in one of your comments : expanding around $x=0$, we would obtain  avery divergent expansion since 
$$x\sqrt{x^3+1}=x+\frac{x^4}{2}-\frac{x^7}{8}+\frac{x^{10}}{16}-\frac{5 x^{13}}{128}+\frac{7
   x^{16}}{256}-\frac{21 x^{19}}{1024}+O\left(x^{21}\right)$$ and integrating termwise the terms would increase more  and more (because of the powers of $2$) with alternating signs leading even to negative values for the definite integral !

Expanding around $x=1$ (that is to say at the mid point of the integration interval), the coefficients become smaller and smaller and the result tends to converge even if slowly.

I hope this makes things clearer for you.

Comment: Why around x=1?

Comment: @YoungMathematician. Just because $\frac{0+2}2=1$ !!

Comment: Thank you for answering me

Comment: @YoungMathematician. You are very welcome ! My answer was not a joke, be sure.

Comment: Why couldn't he use x=0, why did he use x=1?

Comment: @YoungMathematician. You could for sure ! But, may be, you would need more terms since the coefficients could become quite large. It is 6:00am here. Around 9:00am, I shall make a comparison and I shall edit my answer.

Comment: I just saw your comparison, thank you very much

Comment: So basically we have to use a point where the series tends to converge, correct?

Comment: One last question, sorry for bothering you, how do you know that the series converges?

Answer (score 0):

For brevity let $R(x)=\sqrt {1+x^3}\;.$ Let $f(x)=x\sqrt {1+x^3}.$ Then $f'(x)=\frac {1}{2}(\frac {3}{R(x)}-R{x}).$ And $R(x)\in [1,3]$ for $x\in [0,2]$.  So $f'(x)$ is continuous and monotonic for $x\in [0,2]$ with $f'(0)=1$ and $f'(2)=-1.$

Hence, many numerical methods for approximating $\int_0^2f(x)dx$ will give good results with little effort. For example   Simpson's Approximation  $\int_a^b f(x)\approx \left(\frac {b-a}{6}\right) \left(\;f(a)+4f(\frac {a+b}{2})+f(b)\;\right)$ gives $$\int_{(2j)/n}^{(2j+2)/n}f(x)dx\approx F(j,n)=\frac {1}{3n}(\;f(2j/n)+4f((2j+1)/n)+f((2j+2)/n)\;)$$ $$\text {so }\quad \int_0^2f(x)dx\approx \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}F(j,n).$$ Even for very small $n\in \mathbb N$ this should give a good approximation. Tell your computer to calculate it for $1\leq n\leq 10.$