# Integrating a function using double integrals and changing order of integration.

Tags: calculus, integration

When I was online, I stumbled upon this integral:

\[ \int^6_0\int^2_{\frac{x}{3}}\sqrt{1+y^3} \ \mathrm{d}y \ \mathrm{d}x \]

and was unsure of how to evaluate it. My assumption is that a solution may involve a change of order of integration (though I may be wrong - when I tried it certainly didn't make the integral any easier!).

Comment: You can indeed change the order of integration and turn your integral into$$\int_0^2\int_0^{3y}\sqrt{1+y^3}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\int_0^23y\sqrt{1+y^3}\,\mathrm dy,$$but that will not solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm glad to see I managed to change the order of integration correctly, even if it's not the way to answer this problem.

Are you aware of a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: You can check out here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411732/how-can-i-integrate-the-following-function?noredirect=1